# How to Autofilter using a variable (WEEKNUM)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a macro which filters a table according to the current week number.

I've set the variable 'ThisWeek' to give me the current week number:

```
Dim ThisWeek As Variant

ThisWeek = "=WeekNum(TODAY())"
```

This produces the week number, and the column I'm filtering has a list of week numbers (displaying the result of a WEEKNUM formula according to dates in another column)

However I cant get the criteria to accept the variable with the following code:

```
Sheet2.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=ThisWeek
```

I've searched around the web for a couple hours now and tried lots of variables including:

```
Sheet2.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=">=" & ThisWeek, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & ThisWeek
```

I've tried changing the variable type to integer also..

But no luck.. any help hugely appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: By `ThisWeek = "=WeekNum(TODAY())"` it's just a string containing always those same characters. Please refer to my answer to see how to get a week's number in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

The best method I can come with for AutoFilter would be to resolve the TODAY() (*Date* in VBA) to the start and end date then use AutoFilter's Criteria1 and Criteria2 arguments with `Operator:=xlAnd`. Finding the previous Sunday (or any other DOW) and next Saturday is a small matter in VBA using the `Weekday(<date>, [<optional vbDayOfWeek>])` function with some small math.

The Weekday and Date functions are used to resolve dynamic dates like the second Sunday in May or the third Monday in November all the time.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you have to use `Date()` instead of TODAY(), and to get the week's number, use `DatePart()`.

You have to check, how week numbers are counted in your country, and adapt parameter [firstweekofyear](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/datepart-function) of this function.

In Europe e. g. use `DatePart("ww", Date, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)` in VBA.
The corresponding week number function in your worksheet is WEEKNUM(..., 21).

```
Dim ThisWeek As Integer
ThisWeek = DatePart("ww", Date, vbMonday, vbFirstFourDays)
Sheet2.ListObjects("Table3").Range.AutoFilter Field:=10, Criteria1:=ThisWeek
```

Answer (score 0):

It can also be [evaluated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate) (not sure if the `"=" &` part is needed) :

```
ThisWeek = "=" & [WeekNum(TODAY())]
```